# Importing pipe throwing Typescript property does not exist error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm using ionic and have created a custom pipe that takes an object representing image data and returns a URL to that image.

The pipe file looks like this...

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'eventImageLink',
})
export class EventImageLinkPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /**
   * Takes a value and makes it lowercase.
   */
  transform(value: string, ...args) {
    if(value){
      return `//res.cloudinary.com/***/image/upload/w_${window.screen.width},d_item_placeholder_e0lign.jpg/${value.image_version}/${args[0]}/${value.original_image_name}`;
    }
  }
}
```

I have created a `pipes.module.ts` file in the `pipes` folder that imports my pipes...

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { EventImageLinkPipe } from './event-image-link/event-image-link';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EventImageLinkPipe
  ],
  imports: [

  ],
  exports: [
    EventImageLinkPipe
  ]
})
export class PipesModule {}
```

Now before I even import the `PipesModule` into a component for use I am getting the following error...

**Typescript Error**

Property 'image_version' does not exist on type 'string'.

I can't understand why this error is coming up when I haven't even attempted to use it yet and it's quite annoying really. Can someone explain why the pipe is being executed and how I can prevent this error from throwing when I haven't passed any data into the pipe yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you declared input `value: string` which means that you will pass object of type string in it's place in the future. Type of `string` does not have property of an `image_version` as the error says, that is an error and your code simply won't work. You're trying to call `value.image_version` as part of your return result, you will need to change `value` to be of a proper type, not sure which it is in your case.

You could probably have a custom class for it:

```
export class MyImage {
    image_version: string;
    original_image_name: string;
}
```

You can then declare a `value: MyImage` as type of `MyImage` class and Typescript will be fine with it since it contains both properties, `image_version` and `original_image_name` unlike `string` type.

Also, nothing is being executed really, it's just the TypeScript's static-type checking, which prevents you from doing stupid mistakes like this. If you don't want to use static-type checking features, you could also just set it as `value` with no type specified. That way you can pass whatever you want and it will crash at runtime if it's a wrong type of an object instead.

Comment: I knew it was something simple I wasn't seeing. Actually making the image a class is a good idea as well so I did the same. I just changed `value: string` to `value: any` to make sure it will accept a class as well as an object.